# Is there a clean way of using Dispatcher in a .NET Console application?

Tags: c#, .net, command-line-interface, dispatcher

In a .NET (C#) application I would like to have a dispatcher system, similar to dispatch_async() on iOS.

I read on multiple stackoverflow thread that Dispatcher should be used only in the context of a WPF application, but I don't understand why.

I wrote the following code by reading the MSDN documentation, and it is working.
Is there any reason why I should stop using that mechanism?

I don't want to realize later in the process that I am stuck because of something I did not know. (I am new to C# and .NET).

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Threading;


namespace ExcelLeak
{
    class Program
    {
        public static Dispatcher mainSerialQueue;
        public static Dispatcher backgroundSerialQeueue;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            mainSerialQueue = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
            Thread serialQueueThread = new Thread(() =>
            {

                backgroundSerialQeueue = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
                mainSerialQueue.BeginInvoke((System.Action)(() =>
                {
                    doSomeWork();

                }));
                Dispatcher.Run();
            });
            serialQueueThread.Start();
            Dispatcher.Run();
        }
    }

    public static void doSomeWork() {
        mainSerialQueue.BeingInvoke(...)
    }
}
```

What I am doing here is basically getting the Dispatcher for the main thread, which I call `mainSerialQueue` and then create another thread, and get the Dispatcher for it, which I call `backgroundSerialQeueue`.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to invoke code on particlar thread - use SynchronizationContext of appropriate thread. For console app context is empty so you need to initialized it. 2 simple ways are:

- Implement SynchorinzationContext with WPF dispatcher inside and set context for required thread by SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext
- Create instance if System.Windows.Forms.Form class and SynchorinzationContext will be initialzed automitically on executing thread

Why not to use Dispatcher directly? If you'll find and problems with threading later, all you need is to fix SynchorinzationContext. At least you can switch between suggested approaches. Or you can write your own context, but doubt that it will be required.

One more thing - async, await are also build upon SynchorinzationContext.